# XSLT: Switch of automatic line ending adjustment. Or how to produce a single LF character on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, xslt, line-endings

I wrote an XSLT that shall run on both Linux **and** Windows.
The output format must **always** use CRLF as line endings.

Example without all the extra logic:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" method="text" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" xml:space="default"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:variable name="NL"><xsl:text>&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text></xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>Hello</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$NL"/>
        <xsl:text>World</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired output: "Hello\r\nWorld"

Although producing correct output on Linux, on Windows some "intelligence" expands the '&#xa;' to CRLF (because this is the expected line ending on Windows), so I end up with "Hello\r\r\nWorld".

Is there a way to switch off automatic handling of line endings?
(Trials with disable-output-escaping did not succeed)

**Edit:**
We are using Xalan 2.7.2 to process the XSLT
(Since I am within a customer's project I cannot switch to another version of Xalan or even to Saxon)

Running the plain script with IntelliJ will show the same results. Therefore I'm quite sure that there are no subsequent processing steps that spoil my line endings.

**Summary**:
The Xalan option did the trick! Thank you Martin & Fiona.
So the working XSLT looks like this.
Note the three needed steps commented

```
<!-- 1. Add Xalan namespace -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan">

    <!-- 2. Set Xalan option line-separator to fix line endings on every platform -->
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" 
                method="text"
                indent="no"
                omit-xml-declaration="yes"
                xml:space="default"
                xalan:line-separator="&#xd;&#xa;"
    />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- 3. Define new line as LF only on every platform -->
    <xsl:variable name="NL"><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text></xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>Hello</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$NL"/>
        <xsl:text>World</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Well, which tool or API do you use to run the XSLT? Are you sure it is the XSLT processor inserting an additional `\r`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen: Valid point, thank you. Edited question

Comment: I'm no expert on Xalan, but there's nothing in the XSLT spec that allows you to control the choice of line endings with the text output method, and my guess is it will use the default line ending for the platform that it's running on.

Comment: Note that disable-output-escaping is going to be useless, because the text output method doesn't do any escaping in the first place.

Comment: Are you writing Java code to use Xalan? Or just XSLT? I think Xalan has some custom output properties so you could check whether e.g. `<xsl:output xalan:line-separator="&#13;&#10;" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" .../>` gives you consistency but I haven't tested that. There is also https://xalan.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xml/serializer/ToStream.html#setNewLine(char[]) but I am not sure where to apply that.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: Thank you that was the missing option. You should have posted that as an answer! My fault was not to look at the transformer itself. Thought there must be a setting in XSLT itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try one of the two options :

> Option A: Manually set the Xalan XML property
>
> > 1. add below in the stylesheet declaration:

```
xmlns:xalan=http://xml.apache.org/xalan
```

> > 2. then add below in the template:

```
<xsl:output xalan:line-separator="&#10;" />
```

> Option B: Change the $var
>
> > from:

```
<xsl:variable name="NL"><xsl:text>&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text></xsl:variable>
```

> > to:

```
<xsl:variable name="NL"><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text></xsl:variable>
```

You can test it in XML editor which allows you plug in different Transformers:  Xalan, Saxon, Xsltproc.  I test two options with Xalan | Saxon. It produces the consistent result which gives you the confidence to deploy towards API.( XML and Java is platform independent.)

Comment: Thank you! That's the right hint. However, I needed it just the other way round. See my summary I added to my question.

Comment: My apology...@Seven:  please kindly `unaccept` the `Answer`.  @Martin Honnen:  please kindly post your `Answer`.  I am Not able to `delete` it.